# Pentaho report (odoo 8): aggregating fields in PRD

Tags: odoo, pentaho

Creating a report showing the sales pipeline per country.
grouped by 'country':

> -- account abc  -- total opportunities -- total orders -- total invoiced -- year1

I have a query (data source) that looks like:
[odoo query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZnka.jpg)

I need to get the sum of all opportunities and the sum of all orders for each account and then attach each of those total to the account.

- Should I create sub-reports to get the total of planned_revenue & amount_untaxed and then export those value to the main report?
- Is it possible to prepare the data directly in PRD or should I first transform the data to generate the aggregates I will need?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Option 1: one cool thing about using an object based report is you could create a functional field to give you the planned_revenue or amount_untaxed, and then just include them. (like there is with opportunity_count and sale_order_count).  This is certainly the cleanest reporting option if you have the possibility of doing this.
- Option 2: This may need a bit of trial and error, as you would be working from 2 one2many data types (it would be easy to spell out with only one) - you include make sure you include the values you want from the one2many links, but on the main report, you print the account values out as subtotals and hide the body values.  This would be effectively the same as writing subreports, and potentially less flawed, but may have repercussions for accounts with no opportunities or orders.
- Option 3: Transforming it to an SQL based report would allow you to subtotal what you need as well, without a subreport, but this may not be practical and may take away your access to other functional or model data which is not in the database.
- Option 4: Follow your gut and write the subreports.

> Is it possible to prepare the data directly in PRD or should I first transform the data to generate the aggregates I will need?

Not quite sure what you mean here.

Comment: I meant what you explain in option1: to create the fileds in odoo.

Comment: Is it possible to use Pentaho Data Integration and still upload the report in odoo? If not, Would it make sense to keep the report in pentaho server and call it from odoo?

Comment: Option 1 is definitely the cleanest.

Comment: Yes, in fact, using the Data Integration and putting it in Odoo is the main power.  You will need to install the "pentaho for openerp" connector module - available on github at https://github.com/WillowIT/Pentaho-reports-for-OpenERP - You can have the report run from a menu, or as an object action, and you can even have parmeters that will be prompted for in a wizard.